# How can I output to VGA through QEMU (ARM)?

Tags: operating-system, arm, qemu

I feel like fooling around with making a toy OS designed for ARM. I've downloaded the Linux arm-test (http://wiki.qemu.org/Testing) which runs a barebones Linux environment complete with a framebuffer (penguin graphic shown on console) in QEMU.

I've messed around with making relatively basic x86 OSes before so now I want to try on ARM.

Obviously I need a way to get information onto the screen. I haven't started yet but my question is how would I access the graphics device/video memory? I know in x86 you're given access to video memory at a certain address to do what you like, but I've probably spent an hour looking for a similar approach for QEMU ARM and can't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

QEMU apparently emulates a few ARM-based systems, but you probably want to use the [ARM Versatile baseboard](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.subset.boards.rvbaseboards/index.html) model, which has a [PL110 CLCD controller](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0161e/index.html). The big difference between ARM and x86 here is there's no BIOSes to standardise things, so you're <del>forced to do it all yourself</del> free to do what you like ;)

The memory map for your chosen baseboard/CPU combination will tell you where the PL110's configuration registers are mapped, from there you can set it up and point it at whatever bit of RAM you fancy using as your framebuffer - there's no dedicated video memory here.

For reference, [The Linux PL110 driver](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/video/amba-clcd.c?id=f0d55cc1a65852e6647d4f5d707c1c9b5471ce3c) isn't horribly complex, and a quick search turned up [an even simpler example](http://code.google.com/p/pios/source/browse/source/pl110.c) (now archived, but still downloadable).